# Is empty implementation and unused parameter in abstract methods a good approach in certain cases?

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism, solid-principles

I have a situation where I need to parse objects of different types. Most of the types can be parsed in a generic way with the exception of certain types, which require extra filling. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume there is one type which requires performing some special operations, and lets call its parser `SpecialParser`.

In the current implementation, I have a base class called `BaseParser`, which implements an interface `ICustomParser`. A generic parser capable of parsing all the regular types called `GenericParser` and the `SpecialParser`. Both the `GenericParser` and the `SpecialParser` inherit from the `BaseParser` class which implements basic common functionalities.
All the parsers are referenced using the interface and called through a public method implemented in the `BaseParser`. The type of the parser to use is determined using a property implemented in each parser which indicates the types it can parse.

The function which builds the parsed object (`BuildParsedObject()`) has some common parts in all the parsers, but requires some additional logic in the special type parsers.

Currently, the `BaseParser` has an implementation which looks like this:

```cs
public abstract class BaseParser : ICustomParser
{
    // Common methods and functionalities

    protected abstract Type GetParsedType(string typeIdentifier);
    protected abstract void FillConcreteProperties(...);

    public Object BuildParsedObject(JObject objectToBuild)
    {
        // Some common logic.

        var parsedType = GetParsedType(typeIdentifier);

        // Call the specific filling logic if needed. 
        // The order here is important. The concrete filling must be done before the general one.
        FillConcreteProperties(...); 

        // (More common logic) 
        // Fill the general properties for all the types. This method is implemented here in the base class.
        FillGeneralProperties(...);  

        // Cast the object to the parsedType and return it.
        return objectToBuild.ToObject(parsedType);
    }
}
```

The `GenericParser` looks like this:

```cs
public class GenericParser
{
    protected override Type GetParsedType(string typeIdentifier)
    {
        // Perform certain checks on the given <typeIdentifier> and logic in 
        // order to determine the parsed object type and return it.
    }

    protected override void FillConcreteProperties(...)
    { // The implementation is empty here since no special filling is required for the regular types.
    }
}
```

And the `SpecialParser` looks like this:

```cs
public class SpecialParser
{
    protected override Type GetParsedType(string typeIdentifier)
    {
        // The <typeIdentifier> parameter is never used, since the type is already known.
        // So we always just return a hardcoded type for the parser (for e.g. A).
        return typeof(A);
    }

    protected override void FillConcreteProperties(...)
    {
        // Contains an implementation for the specific type parsing and fills the object being built accordingly.
    }
}
```

The advantage of the current implementation is that all the parsers only need to implement the `GetParsedType()` and the `FillConcreteProperties()` methods. All the parsing logic is shared and done at the base class level, and we don't need to replicate the implementation of the `BuildParsedObject()` method.

The disadvantage is that the `GenericParser` doesn't need to implement the `FillConcreteProperties()` method, so we end up with an empty implementation there. And the special parsers don't need to perform a logic in order to determine the output type, so they end up implementing a dummy `GetParsedType()` method and not using the passed argument there.

**Is it fine to have an empty implementation of an abstract method? And an unused parameter in an implemented abstract method? Or is it a bad practice and should be avoided?**

If it should be avoided, **is it a good idea to move the implementation of the `BuildParsedObject()` to the child parser classes and have each one implement it as needed and remove the need to have empty implementation of the `FillConcreteProperties()` and the unused parameter? despite that it would create some kind of duplication there?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it fine to have an empty implementation of an abstract method?

Not really. It is usually an indication of a violation of the Liskov substitution principle.

> And an unused parameter in an implemented abstract method? Or is it a bad practice and should be avoided?

This is also a code smell, indicating that there is low cohesion in your class.

What you could do, is check the decorator pattern of the gang of four. That way you can create extended decorators that will enrich your object according to your business logic.

You can remove the unneeded function this way, run the base function and then enrich your object with whatever new information you may need.

Comment: The problem is that the base function can't be run as is. There is the ```FillConcreteProperties()``` part which need to be done in the middle if needed.. so even if we have a decorator we won't be able to call the base function and then do the extra logic.. That's why I thought to move the implementation of the ```BuildParsedObject()``` to the child classes.
Or did I miss something?